# Mapping various input values to a data accumulation class

Tags: c#, reinventing-the-wheel, reflection

This function takes inputs from multiple different controls on a form, and maps them to values in a data accumulation class.  This code was written specifically to keep logic, data, and display separated.  I ended up at the time using reflection to take the values from the controls and mapping them to variables with the same names in the accumulation class.  The reasoning behind doing it this way was I didn't want a bunch of:

```
variable = control.value
```

Calls being repeated throughout this section of code, and should it end up that I needed additional controls on that form, I wanted to be able to just add the appropriate variable to the accumulation class and let the program handle adding that information to the accumulator dynamically.

I'm posting here to see what if any better ways to do this exist.  (I'm sure there must be one, but this was the method I found that works.)

What I've written works well, and does it's job, but feels like very very bad code.

This is the mapping method:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Updates the random accumulator.  One method to rule *ALL* The random controls!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void UpdateRandomAccumulator ( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
        //Dear Future Me: You are a genius.  You made this work.  Despite overwhelming odds, you are victorious!
        //Be proud future me, when you look upon this method in total confusion, since you probably forgot 
        //*exactly how* it works 10 minutes after closing this class.

        Control control = sender as Control;
        if ( control is TrackBar ) {
            TrackBar tbar = control as TrackBar;
            string controlName = control.Name.Remove ( 0, 9 );
            //okay limiting our MinBads/MaxTourists here.
            if ( controlName.Equals ( "MinNumberOfBadasses" ) || controlName.Equals ( "MaxNumberOfTourists" ) ) {
                if ( tbar.Value >= randAccum.NumberToCreate ) {
                    tbar.Value = randAccum.NumberToCreate;
                }
            }
            foreach ( var prop in randAccum.GetType( ).GetProperties( ) ) {
                if ( controlName == prop.Name ) {
                    if ( prop.PropertyType == typeof(float) ) {
                        prop.SetValue ( randAccum, (float) tbar.Value / 100 );
                    }
                    else if ( prop.PropertyType == typeof(int) ) {
                        prop.SetValue ( randAccum, tbar.Value );
                    }
                    else {
                        Logger.LogEvent ( prop.PropertyType.ToString ( ) );
                    }
                }
            }
            tbar_rnd_MaxNumberOfTourists.Maximum = randAccum.NumberToCreate;
            tbar_rnd_MinNumberOfBadasses.Maximum = randAccum.NumberToCreate;
            if ( tbar_rnd_MaxNumberOfTourists.Value > randAccum.NumberToCreate ) {
                tbar_rnd_MaxNumberOfTourists.Value = randAccum.NumberToCreate;
            }
            if ( tbar_rnd_MinNumberOfBadasses.Value > randAccum.NumberToCreate ) {
                tbar_rnd_MinNumberOfBadasses.Value = randAccum.NumberToCreate;
            }
        }

        if ( control is CheckBox ) {
            CheckBox cbox = control as CheckBox;
            string controlName = cbox.Name.Remove ( 0, 8 );
            //because use Ratio is notted, we have to set it by hand.  
            //The For loop is left incase we add any more checkboxes.
            if ( controlName.Equals ( "useRatio" ) ) {
                tbar_rnd_FtMRatio.Enabled = !cbox.Checked;
                randAccum.useRatio = !cbox.Checked;
            }
            else {
                foreach ( var prop in randAccum.GetType( ).GetProperties( ) ) {
                    if ( controlName == prop.Name ) {
                        if ( prop.PropertyType == typeof(bool) ) {
                            prop.SetValue ( randAccum, cbox.Checked );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        randAccum.NumberToCreate = randAccum.Pilots + randAccum.Engineers + randAccum.Scientists;
        UpdateRandomDisplay ( );
    }
```

And here's the accumulation class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace KerbalTherapist.Accumulators {
public class RandomAccumulator {
    //number of kerbals to create
    public int NumberToCreate { get; set; }



    public bool useRatio { get; set; }

    public bool isKerman { get; set; }

    //gendersettings;
    public float FtMRatio { get; set; }
    //ability scores
    public float MinStupid { get; set; }

    public float MaxStupid { get; set; }

    public float MinBrave { get; set; }

    public float MaxBrave { get; set; }

    public int MinNumberOfBadasses { get; set; }

    public int MaxNumberOfTourists { get; set; }

    //Profession Ratios
    public int Pilots { get; set; }

    public int Engineers { get; set; }

    public int Scientists { get; set; }

    public RandomAccumulator ( ) {
        NumberToCreate = 1;
        FtMRatio = 0;
        useRatio = true; //needs to be true by default.
        MinStupid = 0.0f;
        MaxStupid = 0.0f;
        MinBrave = 0.0f;
        MaxBrave = 0.0f;
        MinNumberOfBadasses = 0;
        MaxNumberOfTourists = 0;

        Pilots = 0;
        Engineers = 0;
        Scientists = 0;
    }

    public RandomAccumulator Reset ( ) {
        return new RandomAccumulator ( );
    }
}
```

Comment: Lol that comment for future you is silly :D TBH if you did just a bunch of assignments -yes I know you're trying to avoid that- you would never have this problem. The code would be straight forward for anyone to understand anytime in future within few seconds. Magic and technology don't go together well :)

Comment: @slepic, yeah this was a case of "Why spend 5 minutes typing all the assignments when I can spend 3 hours automating the process"

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview! Could you please elaborate on this *feels like very very bad code*? Why do you have that feeling? From what perspective does it feel bad?

Comment: You haven't specified the purpose of the code. Could it be that you're writing a KSP mod?

Comment: Please tag the proper `.NET` environment (Windows Forms, Web ASP.NET, WPF ..etc.), and an explanation on what you've experienced that led you to this code (what are you trying to achieve).?

Comment: *I didn't want a bunch of ...*  => Get rid of all that cyclomatic-complexity inducing code and generate controls from a data structure containing associated names, control types, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite frankly I'm not sure what your code fragment does, so I've reviewed your code in the way how can we improve legibility.

### Split the `UpdateRandomAccumulator` method

- You can easily extract the `TrackBar` and `Checkbox` handling code into their own methods
- After that the `UpdateRandomAccumulator` method would like something like this

```
private void UpdateRandomAccumulator(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var control = sender as Control;
    if (control is TrackBar tbar)
    {
        HandleTrackbar(tbar, control.Name.Remove(0, 9));
    }
    else if (control is CheckBox cbox)
    {
        HandleCheckbox(cbox, cbox.Name.Remove(0, 8));
    }

    randAccum.NumberToCreate = randAccum.Pilots + randAccum.Engineers + randAccum.Scientists;
    UpdateRandomDisplay();
}
```

- Please be aware that this `Name.Remove(x, y)` is super fragile so try to avoid it if possible

#### The `HandleTrackbar`

- As I've stated in the first sentence without proper context it is impossible to know what your code really does

  - So, my suggestions here might be not applicable

```
static string[] ControlNames = { "MinNumberOfBadasses", "MaxNumberOfTourists" };
void HandleTrackbar(TrackBar tbar, string controlName)
{
    if (ControlNames.Contains(controlName) && tbar.Value >= randAccum.NumberToCreate)
    { 
        tbar.Value = randAccum.NumberToCreate;
    }

    var prop = randAccum.GetType().GetProperty(controlName);

    if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(float))
    {
        prop.SetValue(randAccum, tbar.Value / 100f);
    }
    else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(int))
    {
        prop.SetValue(randAccum, tbar.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        Logger.LogEvent(prop.PropertyType.ToString());
    }
            
    tbar_rnd_MaxNumberOfTourists.Maximum = randAccum.NumberToCreate;
    tbar_rnd_MaxNumberOfTourists.Value = tbar_rnd_MaxNumberOfTourists.Value > randAccum.NumberToCreate
        ? randAccum.NumberToCreate
        : tbar_rnd_MaxNumberOfTourists.Value;

    tbar_rnd_MinNumberOfBadasses.Maximum = randAccum.NumberToCreate;
    tbar_rnd_MinNumberOfBadasses.Value = tbar_rnd_MinNumberOfBadasses.Value > randAccum.NumberToCreate
        ? randAccum.NumberToCreate
        : tbar_rnd_MinNumberOfBadasses.Value;
}
```

- I've replaced your control name check logic to a collection lookup
- As far I understand your code you don't need to get all properties, rather you are looking for a specific one based on the control name

  - So, I've removed your `foreach` loop and replaced your `GetProperties` to `GetProperty` call
- I've replaced your `(float)tbar.Value / 100` to `tbar.Value / 100f` because  the intent is more explicit here IMHO
- I've also replaced your guard expression for value assignments with ternary conditional operators

#### `HandleCheckbox`

```
void HandleCheckbox(ChechBox cbox, string controlName)
{
    if (controlName.Equals("useRatio"))
    {
        tbar_rnd_FtMRatio.Enabled = !cbox.Checked;
        randAccum.useRatio = !cbox.Checked;
        return;
    }

    var prop = randAccum.GetType().GetProperty("prop.Name");

    if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
    {
        prop.SetValue(randAccum, cbox.Checked);
    }
}
```

- More or less the same simplification as before
- +1: I've used early exit to avoid having `else` block

### RandomAccumulator

- Please use consistent naming for your properties (`NumberToCreate`, `useRatio`, etc.)
- Set properties' default value on the auto-generated propreties rather than inside a dedicated ctor

  - Set the default value **only if** it differs from the [runtime default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values)

```
public class RandomAccumulator
{
    public int NumberToCreate { get; set; }

    public bool UseRatio { get; set; } = true;

    public bool IsKerman { get; set; }

    public float FtMRatio { get; set; }

    public float MinStupid { get; set; }

    public float MaxStupid { get; set; }

    public float MinBrave { get; set; }

    public float MaxBrave { get; set; }

    public int MinNumberOfBadasses { get; set; }

    public int MaxNumberOfTourists { get; set; }

    public int Pilots { get; set; }

    public int Engineers { get; set; }

    public int Scientists { get; set; }

    public RandomAccumulator Reset()
        => new();
}
```